# Wrong CurrentCulture

Tags: asp.net, localization

I'm using Web API 2 and for some reason the `CurrentCulture` value is set to English.

My system language is pt-BR, the location is correctly set to Brazil and I have `<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />` in my `Web.config`. I've also checked the registry and my country code is 32 (Brazil).

What else can I do?

Comment: Did you set `enableClientBasedCulture` in `<globalization>`?

Comment: @haim770 No, it's not set. In that case, it should be using the server's settings, right?